# kendoui: start listView in edit mode

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

i have a kendoui list view which i want to load up in edit mode so thats its immediately editable. heres my  list view

```
var claimListView = $("#formClaim").kendoListView({
      dataSource: claimData,
      template: kendo.template($("#viewTemplate").html()),
      editTemplate: kendo.template($("#formTemplate").html())
  }).data("kendoFormClaim");
```

Ive tried this put i get a reference error

```
claimListView.edit(claimListView.element.children().first());
```

what am i  doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: The provided code looks correct. Show us how your data looks like and the template declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I didn't show the data source as everything in the list view is working fine, it's just getting to load in edit mode that I'm having the problem with. Here's a link to the test page I'm building, see if you can spot anything. Thanks again [heres the link to demo](http://login.chandlersimmons.co.uk/claims/view.php?id_clm=2)

Comment: Clicking the "Edit" button seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a code typo in the last ".data(..." part.

it needs to be:

```
.data("kendoListView");
```

not:

```
.data("kendoFormClaim");
```

thats why you get reference error, the variable is not recognized as a listview because of the type and it doesnt have an edit method then.

Comment: ive now corrected the issue but still no joy, im not getting the error now but its not loading in edit mode after adding the .edit etc code directory below. you can you the previous link to see. Im having diffficulty using this website to post code, or ever returns... lol.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not sure without a fiddle example where I could play around in, but the problem now could be that you try to go into edit mode before the datasource gets fully loaded. The datasource loading happens async, so your edit code can fire before its done. The way I would make sure this wouldnt happen is maybe to define a DataBound event handler on the listview and add the edit code there. That way its gonna load up the listview first and only once it's fully loaded will it go to edit mode